# Can ping but cannot be pinged

Tags: windows-7, networking, ping, network-discovery

At my company we have a notebook (Dell Precision 7510) with Windows 7, logged into domain that started acting strange.

It can ping others and access anything that it has to (remote, file shares, etc.) but when pinged from any other device it returns ping timeout.
Also network discovery is turned on but can discover only itself.
This problem is the same on LAN and wireless as well.
When pingig, the dnsname is resolved and shows the correct ip address. Pingig the ip address also results the same.

I know the internet is full of this topic, but I have tried most of the solutions and non of them worked. Also reinstalling Windows is always an option but I would like to figure out what went wrong here.

Already tried:

- `sfc /scannow`
- reinstalled lan driver (from dell support site)
- `winsh netsock reset`
- entered safe mode with networking - same result -> probably not software problem
- Windows firewall is turned off - from services as well. (same on all computers)
- checked `ipconfig /all` - default gateway and subnet masks are set fine
- deleted dhcp reservation and renewed IP
- `arp -a -d`
- checked for hidden drivers that may cause problems: `set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1`
- compared running services to another notebook that works good, it looked ok
- re joined the notebook to the domain
- tried to `tracert` the notebook it did 30 timeout `*` hops

I will update my post after I try something new.
If you have any questions about the notebooks configuration, just leave a comment and I will update my question.

Every new ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What I usually run on computers with connectivity issues is `Netsh winsock reset catalog Netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log`. If you have domain priviliges, have you unjoined and rejoined it to the domain?

Comment: You may try [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/#download) or [winDump](https://www.winpcap.org/windump/) to test network with network packet analyzing.

Comment: @Confuzing I will try your command tomorrow and see what we get. Yes we did try to un/re join it to the domain as well

Comment: Is it just pings not getting through? Can you, for example, RDP into the laptop?

Comment: @Biswa good idea, maybe the packets are lost somewhere in the routing process. It would be good to find out where the packets are sent

Comment: @Darren I did not try RDP, but tried to connect to the notebook with RPC services, WMI queries, or map its local drive. They didn't work. From the notebook it is possible to access other computers

Comment: OK, then some more information about its physical location compared to other devices in the network. Is it on the same switch or on a different segment?

Comment: @Darren - Honestly I don't know the exact network topology of the building, but tried it on multiple wall ports in the same office (with/without docking station), also wireless works on a different subnet then LAN and it produces the same problem, this is why I think it is an issue on the notebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the problem after some heavy troubleshooting.

Checkpoint vpn client caused the problem.
I was thinking of this, but dropped the idea because I tried safe mode.

After reinstalling it worked fine.

Lesson learned. Never trust your VPN client.

Comment: Deserves an upvote just for coming back updating us. Doesn't always happen.

Comment: I knew about this issue before I read your post, but I found that as long as the Checkpoint service is enabled and running, it'll be fine. Then that stopped working and I found you have to actually keep Checkpoint running in the system tray, i.e the actual process running in the background. However, something broke it in Windows 10 20H2, so a complete uninstall fixed the issue. I'm glad I found this, as this confirms the same Checkpoint issue I've had.